# flex: Refrashing cusom mxml component on button click

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have defined small MXML component which calls web service which returns random number on request, then my component displays the number.

How do I refresh the MXML from main application control, so it will recall server again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by refreshing the component. As per my understanding, you need to have a button or some similar control and on click event, call the webservice again and get the random number and display again. Or set that to a `Bindable` variable so that it will be displayed automatically.